# Transform List of Lists into a Summary Table

Tags: r

Relative newbie to R here. I am having difficulty transforming a list of lists into a cleaner summary table. Generally speaking, I am looking to apply numerous functions to a dataframe with multiple columns and obtain a summary table as an output where the rownames are the names of the functions and the column names are the same as the column names of the dataframe.

Take the following sample code. Say I create the following simple dataframe:

```
a = seq(100,110,2)
b = seq(200,220,4)
df = data.frame(a,b)
```

Next, say I create the following two sample functions, each of which will take a numerical vector and result in a single numerical number:

```
func1 = function(x) sum(x)**2
func2 = function(x) sqrt(sum(x))
```

I then wanted to wrap these two functions into a single function which will run them both:

```
combined_func = function(x){
  combined = list("func1" = func1(x), "func2" = func2(x))
  return(as.data.frame(do.call(rbind, combined)))
}
```

I then applied this "combined function" to both columns of my dataframe, like this:

```
lapply(df, combined_func)
```

And here was the output I obtained:

```
$a
               V1
func1 396900.0000
func2     25.0998

$b
                V1
func1 1.587600e+06
func2 3.549648e+01
```

While the output is technically correct, I hate the formatting. As stated at the top, I'd like the end result to be the names of the functions as the rownames, and the names of the columns ("a" and "b" in this example) to be the column names. I'd like the result to look like this:

```
                  a            b
func1   396900.0000 1.587600e+06
func2       25.0998 3.549648e+01
```

I've spent the last few days searching StackOverflow and can't seem to figure out how to accomplish this. Any and all help would be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A slightly different approach, which saves the need for the the `combined_func`

```
funs <- list(func1 = func1, func2 = func2)

t(sapply(funs, mapply, df))

#-----
                a            b
func1 396900.0000 1.587600e+06
func2     25.0998 3.549648e+01
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
combined <- lapply(df, combined_func)

table <- do.call(cbind, combined)

colnames(table) <- list('a', 'b')
```

This gives us:

```
               a            b
func1 396900.0000 1.587600e+06
func2     25.0998 3.549648e+01
```

Comment: @kamiks np, I just updated with a way to rename the colnames.

Comment: Thank you so much!!!! You solved what was a very frustrating week-long seach. I figured there would be some off-the-shelf function or package that would simply take a dataframe and a list of functions as arguments and create such a table. But this works. Again thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Could it be as easy as

`Reduce(cbind, lapply(df, combined_func))`

?

Comment: Also works! Just requires colnames to be changed to those of original dataframe.

Comment: yeah, also `as.data.frame(combined)`. many ways to skin a pig, don't trust R too much with automatic naming.

Answer (score 0):

You can change `combined_func` to :

```
combined_func = function(x){
  c("func1" = func1(x), "func2" = func2(x))
}
```

and call it with `sapply` :

```
sapply(df, combined_func)
#             a         b
#func1 396900.0 1587600.0
#func2     25.1      35.5
```